# On mouseover or On click function is not working properly

Tags: javascript

on mouseover or on click function is not working properly. It is working first time only. when I am going to click or hover it the second time, it's not working. Please help.

```
`<script>
function displayDate()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
function a()
{
document.write("Show Time");
}
</script>

<div id='demo' onmouseover='displayDate()' onmouseout='a()'>Show Time</div>`
```

Comment: Try 'javascript:displayDate();' and 'javascript:a();'

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but you are using inline javascript...can you use a library like jQuery? If so, there is a very easy answer.

Comment: Click event won't do anything, at least when you trigger "mouseenter" or "mouseout", anyway it works great to me http://jsfiddle.net/k8K75/

Answer (score 2):

```
document.write('Show date');
```

The line above overwrites the entire document, and removes the element, so you no longer have an element with an event handler, that's why it only works once.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, first showing "Show time", and then on mouseout "Show date", but you should probably be doing something like :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Show date';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wwT69/)

Comment: I just update the code. your code is not working for me. Sorry